# AWS restrict specific ECR images to specific IAM users?

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-ecr

I'm running a Docker host based on AWS Lightsail targeted individuals for hosting their spare time smaller scale projects.

I'd love to also offer Docker image hosting via AWS ECR, but obviously I wouldn't want one customer's images to be accessible by another customer.

I'd like to use one AWS account for hosting everything on, so that my customers won't need to create an AWS account to get started.

Is that possible somehow? Can I create individual IAM users which only have read and write access to specific images?

Comment: Use different repositories and policies for each user. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policies.html

Comment: If you put your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use different repositories and policies for each user.

[Amazon ECR Repository Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policies.html)